# Obtener productos más vendidos en una colección de órdenes de mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Tengo la siguiente estructura de una colección de órdenes.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("624869f6ffbf6833d051faf9"), 
    "id_user" : 112,
    "totalAmount" : 285,
    "sales" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("624869f6ffbf6833d051fafb"), 
            "id_vendor" : 101,
            "products" : [
                {

                    "_id" : ObjectId("624869f6ffbf6833d051fafd"), 
                    "id_product" : "01", 
                    "count" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "descrip" : "Vendo pollo crudo ", 
                    "name" : "Pollo", 
                    "price" : 45
                }, 
                { 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("624869f6ffbf6833d051fafe"),  
                    "id_product" : "02", 
                    "count" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "descrip" : "vendo pino de olor",
                    "name" : "Pino", 
                    "price" : 150
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("624869f6ffbf6833d051fafc"), 
            "id_vendor" : 103,
            "products" : [
                {

                    "_id" : ObjectId("624869f6ffbf6833d051fafa"), 
                    "id_product" : "04", 
                    "count" : NumberInt(2), 
                    "descrip" : "", 
                    "name" : "Jamón", 
                    "price" : 45
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

Estoy intentando obtener los productos más vendidos y entiendo que debo agrupar de alguna manera por el atributo del nombre del producto y mostrar la cantidad de veces que se repite en las órdenes emitidas.

Mi conocimiento es de SQL y recién empiezo con Mongodb. La sentencia que me gustaría poder aplicar sería algo así:

select sales.products.name, count(sales.products.name)
from orders
group by sales.products.name
order by count(sales.products.name) desc;

No sabría llevarlo a Mongodb.

Saludos y muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

Comment: ¿Al menos has intentado hacer algo? En la documentación hay suficientes ejemplos sobre como lograr lo que quieres. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Si muestras lo que has intentado, tu pregunta estaría aún más completa. Saludos

Comment: Probablemente puedas hacer algo con la ayuda del (aggregate)[https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) , usando `unwind`

Answer (score 1):

Perdonen la demora en responder a las preguntas, estuve algo complicado de tiempo.

Gracias a Mauricio y Pipe por colaborar.

Les dejo la consulta que apliqué por si puede ser de utilidad.

Lo primero que tuve que hacer fue aplicar el operador $unwind para extraer los subdocumentos del array sales y luego otro $unwind para extraer los subdocumentos del array products.

Luego de esto utilicé el operador $project para quedarme con los campos que necesitaba (en este caso id_product y el name).

Como paso siguiente apliqué el operador $group y agrupé por el campo id_product y por último ordene utilizando el operador $sort.

Saludos y espero que sirva de ayuda para otros que como yo se inicien en este mundo de mongodb.

```
db.orders.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$sales"
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$sales.products"
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "id_product" : "$sales.products.id_product", 
                "name" : "$sales.products.name"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : { 
                    "id_producto" : "$id_product", 
                    "nombre" : "$name"
                }, 
                "cantidad" : { 
                    "$sum" : 1
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$sort" : { 
                "count" : -1
            }
        }
    ]
);
```